# Content displaying on top of and below bootstrap sidenav

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, menu

I've put together a sidenav accordion. The problem is that when side scrolling the content goes on top of and below the sidenav. I would, if possible, like to have the content 'pushed' aside so to speak, but still have it always visible.

I've tried using overflow and display properties on the page as well as the sidenav, but those properties seem to more or less change where the content starts relative to the sidenav, but the same problem remains. I've also tried to mess with the margins and padding, but that hasn't worked either. Anyone know what might be going on, or if this is even possible?

I've attached a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uv1IaqysiSlXMMdxRGS7?p=preview) to see, I've tried to strip down the code as much as I could while still being able to show what the problem is. You may need to make the view screen bigger to see it (another bug I need to iron out, but haven't really looked into it yet).

Here is my markup

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.3.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-s1 navbar-side left" role="navigation">

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <ul id="side" class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">

        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Forms</a></li>

        <li class="panel">
          <a class="accordion-toggle" data-target="#customerSupport" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#side"> Customer Support <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
          <ul id="customerSupport" class="collapse nav">
            <li>
              <a class="sublink" href=""> <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Reconciliation</a>
            </li>
            <!-----<li class="panel">
                        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-target="#affliate" data-toggle="collapse">Affliate <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                        <ul id="affliate" class="collapse nav">
                            <li><a class="sublink" href=""> <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Categories</a></li>
                            <li><a class="sublink" href=""> <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Products</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>-->
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="panel">
          <a class="accordion-toggle" data-target="#iceTravel" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#side"> Menu <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
          <ul id="iceTravel" class="collapse nav">
            <li>
              <a class="sublink" href=""> <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Reconciliation</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="sublink" href=""> <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Spiff Tracker</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="panel">
          <a class="accordion-toggle" data-target="#lifestyles" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#side"> Menu <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
          <ul id="lifestyles" class="collapse nav">
            <li>
              <a class="sublink" href=""> <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Reconciliation</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="panel">
          <a class="accordion-toggle" data-target="#marriot" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#side"> Menu <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
          <ul id="marriot" class="collapse nav">
            <li>
              <a class="sublink" href=""> <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Reconciliation</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="panel">
          <a class="accordion-toggle" data-target="#rciTravel" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#side"> Menu <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
          <ul id="rciTravel" class="collapse nav">
            <li>
              <a class="sublink" href=""> <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Adjustment</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="sublink" href=""> <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Cancellation</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="sublink" href=""> <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Manual Push</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="sublink" href=""> <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Reconciliation</a>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li>
              <a class="sublink" href=""> <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Escalations</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4" id="memberInfo">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title">Member Information</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Member ID" />
            <span class="input-group-btn" style="width:0px;"></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Brand ID" />
          </div>
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Member's First Name" />
            <span class="input-group-btn" style="width:0px;"></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Member's Last Name" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="reservationInfo">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Reservation Information</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="container">
          <form class="col-sm-6" role="form">

            <div id="paymentInfo" class="col-sm-12">
              <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h3 class="panel-title">Payment Information</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <div class="container">
                    <form role="form">

                      <div class="form-inline" style="margin-left: 114px">
                        <div class="form-group-sm">
                          <div class="btn-group-sm form-inline">

                            <input type="text" id="rg-from" name="rg-from" value="" class="form-control">
                            <input type="text" id="rg-from" name="rg-from" value="" class="form-control">
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group-sm">
              <div class="form-group-sm">
                <label for="comment" style="width: auto">Reservation Names:</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" id="comment"></textarea>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="comment" style="width: auto">Witness Recording ID:</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" id="comment"></textarea>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="comment" style="width: auto">Booking Description/Notes:</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" id="comment"></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <legend>Legend</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-4">Submit Button</button>
    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

And my CSS

```
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding-left: 200px;

}

/* Set padding to keep content from hitting the edges */
.body-content {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

/* Override the default bootstrap behavior where horizontal description lists 
   will truncate terms that are too long to fit in the left column 
*/
.dl-horizontal dt {
    white-space: normal;
}




/*----------SideNav------------*/
.circle-tile {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
.circle-tile-heading {
    border: 3px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    border-radius: 100%;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 0 auto -40px;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    width: 80px;
}
.circle-tile-heading .fa {
    line-height: 80px;
}
.circle-tile-content {
    padding-top: 50px;
}
.circle-tile-number {
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1;
    padding: 5px 0 15px;
}
.circle-tile-description {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.circle-tile-footer {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.circle-tile-footer:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    text-decoration: none;
}
.circle-tile-heading.dark-blue:hover {
    background-color: #2E4154;
}
.circle-tile-heading.green:hover {
    background-color: #138F77;
}
.circle-tile-heading.orange:hover {
    background-color: #DA8C10;
}
.circle-tile-heading.blue:hover {
    background-color: #2473A6;
}
.circle-tile-heading.red:hover {
    background-color: #CF4435;
}
.circle-tile-heading.purple:hover {
    background-color: #7F3D9B;
}
.tile-img {
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

/* Edit Below to Customize Widths > 768px */
@media (min-width:768px) {

.side-nav {
  margin-left: -225px;
  left: 225px;
  width: 225px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
}

.side-nav >li .dropdown > ul .dropdown-menu {
  min-width: 225px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
}

.side-nav>li>a {
  width: 225px;
}



.navbar-collapse {
    padding-left: 15px !important;
    padding-right: 15px !important;
}

}

/* New */

.navbar-side .side-nav .panel {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

.navbar-side ul.side-nav {
  background-color: #2C3E50;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #54677A;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid #54677A;
}

.navbar-side .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {    /*-----------------------*/
  background-color: #2980B9 !important;
}

.navbar-side .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {   /*-----------------------*/
  background-color: #34495E !important;
}

.navbar-side .navbar-nav > li > a:active {
 background-color: darkblue !important;    /*-----------------------*/
 color: #000;
 outline: medium none;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)
}

.navbar-side .navbar-nav > li > a {
 background-color: darkcyan;
 outline: medium none;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); /*-----------------------*/
}

.navbar-side .navbar-nav .sublink {
  color: #000 ;
}

.navbar-side .side-nav li, .navbar-side .side-nav li.panel {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #142638;
 border-top: 1px solid #54677A;
 border-left: 1px solid #54677A;
 border-right: 1px solid #54677A;
}
.navbar-side .side-nav li.panel ul li {
 border-bottom: medium none;
 border-top: medium none;
}

/* Top Menu Color */


.navbar-s1 .navbar-text {
  color: #999999;
}

.navbar-s1 .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #999999;
}

.navbar-s1 .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-s1 .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-s1 .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-s1 .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-s1 .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #080808;
}

.navbar-s1 .navbar-nav > .disabled > a,
.navbar-s1 .navbar-nav > .disabled > a:hover,
.navbar-s1 .navbar-nav > .disabled > a:focus {
  color: #444444;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-s1 .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #333333;
}

.navbar-s1 .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-s1 .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #333333;
}

.navbar-s1 .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.navbar-s1 .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-s1 .navbar-form {
  border-color: #101010;
}

.navbar-s1 .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar-s1 .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.navbar-s1 .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #080808;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-s1 .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .dropdown-header {
    border-color: #080808;
  }
  .navbar-s1 .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu .divider {
    background-color: #080808;
  }
  .navbar-s1 .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    color: #999999;
  }
  .navbar-s1 .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-s1 .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  .navbar-s1 .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a,
  .navbar-s1 .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
  .navbar-s1 .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #080808;
  }
  .navbar-s1 .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a,
  .navbar-s1 .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a:hover,
  .navbar-s1 .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a:focus {
    color: #444444;
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}

.navbar-s1 .navbar-link {
  color: #999999;
}

.navbar-s1 .navbar-link:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}


.divider {
  height: 1px;
  width:100%;
  display:block; /* for use on default inline elements like span */
  margin: 0px 0;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;}



/*--------Custom Classes----------*/
#memberInfo {
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.calBoxes input[type=text] {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-left: none;
}
```

I did base my sidenav off of [this](http://codepen.io/rudyvalencia/pen/JmowD) that I found as well. Let me know if you need any clarification or other info! Thanks!

### Edit

Following the suggestions I added the col-sm-x properties, but now the navbar displays on the top of the page and the content below that, where I'm wanting them side by side. I also made a change to my CSS to accommodate, which is shown below.

```
.side-nav {
  margin-left: -25px;
  left: 225px;
  width: 225px;
  position: static;
  top: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

I changed the left margin and the overflow property as the navbar went off of the page. I also updated the plunker as well.

Comment: Bootstrap give us a 12 column grid, You need to set your side nav in 3 column(Ex. col-sm-3) and main contain in 9 column grid(Ex. col-sm-9). I hope it work.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding something I tried that, per yours and another's comments. See my update above.

Answer (score 0):

Start by wrapping your page in a `container-fluid` to give rows proper alignment and padding. Then wrap your sidenav and content in a `row`, and, using Bootstrap's grid column system of 12, assign the number of columns to your respective elements. For example `col-md-2` for sidebar and `col-md-10` for content.

Comment: hmmm, I did as you suggested and made a small change in my css to accommodate, but now the navbar displays on top and the content is below everything. Maybe I misunderstood something? I updated my plunker with your suggestions.